# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `focused` of type `object` supplied to `withStyles(SingleDatePicker)`, expected `boolean

Tags: reactjs, date, react-hooks

I am trying to implement the SingleDatePicker but I keep getting the aforementioned error. What am I doing wrong since the I am clearly setting the initial value to a boolean.

Here is my implementation:

```
  const [calendarFocused, setCalendarFocus] = useState(false);   --this a boolean not an object?
  const [createdAt, setCreatedAt] = useState(moment());

  const onChange = (event) =>
    setTimesheet({
      ...timesheet,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });

  const onDateChange = (createdAt) => setCreatedAt(createdAt);

  const onCalendarFocusChange = (focused) => setCalendarFocus(focused);   return (
    <form>
      <h5 className='text-primary'>Add time</h5>
      <input
        type='text'
        placeholder='Enter title'
        title='title'
        value={title}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      <select name='project'>
        <option value='project' disabled defaultValue>
          Choose your project
        </option>
        <option value='1'>Project 1</option>
        <option value='2'>Project 2</option>
        <option value='3'>Project 3</option>
      </select>
      <SingleDatePicker
        date={createdAt} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null
        onDateChange={onDateChange} // PropTypes.func.isRequired
        focused={calendarFocused} // PropTypes.bool
        onFocusChange={onCalendarFocusChange} // PropTypes.func.isRequired
        id='#123' // PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      />
      <div>
        <input
          type='submit'
          value='Add new time'
          className='waves-effect waves-light btn-large'
        />
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you please share how `SingleDatePicker` looks like?

Comment: I'm having the same issue too. How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same issue. if you console.log(calendarFocused), it will print an object [focused : false] to the console. As SingleDatePicker expects a boolean, this will throw an error.

To fix the issue, edit your 'focused' in SingleDatePicker to the following:

```js
    <SingleDatePicker
       date={createdAt} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null
       onDateChange={onDateChange} // PropTypes.func.isRequired
       focused={calendarFocused.focused} // PropTypes.bool
       onFocusChange={onCalendarFocusChange} // PropTypes.func.isRequired
       id='#123' // PropTypes.string.isRequired
    />
```